# Running playbook in host A to get value and pass on the value to task where it execute locally

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Execute a Task to get the hostname in windows machine and store in variable called HstName. Then I have to use the variable to create a folder in GCP dynamically. My GCP module works only on localhost

Ansible version : 2.7

Task 1: Target host windows, to get the hostname
Task 2: "gcp_storage" module uses localhost for creating an object inside storage bucket.

```
 hosts: win
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
  connection: winrm
  become_method: runas
  become_user: admin
  vars:
    ansible_become_password: '}C7I]8zH@5cPDE8'
    gcp_object: "gcp-shareddb-bucket/emeraldpos/stage/"

  tasks:
  - name: hostname
    win_command: hostname
    register: Hstname

  - set_fact:
      Htname: "{{ Hstname.stdout | trim}}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{Htname}}"

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Create folder under EMERALDPOS
    gc_storage:
      bucket: gcp-shareddb-bucket
      object: "{{gcp_object}}{{Htname}}"
      mode: create
      region: us-west2
      project: sharedBucket-228905
      gs_access_key: "NAKJSAIUS231219237LOKM"
      gs_secret_key: "XABSAHSKASAJS:OAKSAJNDADIAJAJD:N<MNMN"
```

Ansible should create gcp-shareddb-bucket/emeraldpos/stage/HOSTNAME in gcp storage object

Comment: You want `{{ hostvars["win"].Htname }}` since `set_fact:` is _per host_ and `localhost` was not in the first playbook (assuming `win` is the name of one host, else you'll need to go spelunking around in `groups` to pull off something akin to `hostvars[(hostvars.groups["win"]|first)].Htname`)

Comment: Thanks for the response **Matthew**, My environment hosts file has IP alone under **[win]** with which playbook will log in to windows machine to get the hostname and set it as a dynamic parameter called **Htname** and then logs in to GCP storage to create an object. If this doesn't work can split GCP object creation into separate playbook and call the playbook inside main? Please suggest if i am wrong here